# Javascript / Typescript : Flattening an Object accessed via firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from a firebase database. I am getting the Object structure this way:

[image]

I want to be made this way:

[image]

Is there any elegant way of doing this in the frontend or is it better to make the changes in the tree structure in the database?

The only reason I have it in the current form, is that it makes it easier for me to form a tree hierarchy structure later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do it manually, but thankfully it's not too hard. If `snap` is the firebase snapshot you are getting that includes `postId/...` as it's child, then:

```
const results = [];
snap.forEach(child => {
    child.forEach(grandchild => {
        results.push({
            id: child.key,
            uid: grandchild.key,
            ...grandchild.val(),
        });
    });
});

// Do stuff with results...
```